# Set tab name in redirect to route in laravel

Tags: laravel

in laravel 8 i will redirect the user to a route after doing the query.
There are many tabs on the page where I want the user to be transferred
I wrote the code like this
(Of course I know it's wrong, but I wanted to try, and yet I did not think of another way

```
return redirect()->route('admin.auth.user.show', $user . "#edit-information")->withFlashSuccess(__('The user was successfully updated.'));
```

I get an error with this code

What is your solution?

Comment: Setting the page title or other things like that isn't really the responsibility of a redirect. It would fall under the responsibility of the page that gets returned *after* the redirect.

Comment: You mean there is no way?  @BrianThompson

Comment: I'm saying it doesn't make sense. It may be possible, not sure.

Comment: You can set the tab you want into session (`session()->flash('active_tab', '#edit-information');`), then set that as the default active tab in your HTML or via JS once the page redirects. [Update your code](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69352655/edit) to include your HTML or JS for the tabs so we can help further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do to activate for example bootstrap tab based on #web paramater is use the redirect() method like this:

```
 return redirect()->route('backend.settings.show', ['eshop' => $eshop->id, '#homeImages']);
```

Eshop is regular route parameter but '#homeImages' is added to the end of the route which is then picked up by the js on page load.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel there is a `withFragment` method, which add a fragment identifier to the URL.

```
return redirect()->route('admin.auth.user.show', ['user' => $user])->withFragment('edit-information');
```

https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Http/RedirectResponse.html#method_withFragment